# Recieving message on socketio and forward/reroute/send to websocket server in Python

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io

i'm writing a bridge between two servers and am puzzled on how to do it properly.
I have a socketio server that sends me a message which i need to transform and reroute to a websocket.

Look at my first try:

```
import socketio
import asyncio
import websockets


the_socketio_adress = 'http://localhost:1234'
the_websocket_adress = 'ws://localhost:1235'

my_socketio_client = socketio.Client()

#THIS DOES NOT WORK
@my_socketio_client.on('message')
def on_message(data):
    messageId = data['messageId']
    value = data['value'] if 'value' in data else None
    if messageId == "requiredTag":
        event = {"sender":"myclients_name",messageId:value}
        **websocket.send(json.dumps(event))**
#THIS DOES NOT WORK:END

my_socketio_client.connect(my_socketio_adress)


async def listen_to_websocket_server():
    async with await websockets.connect(my_websocket_adress) as websocket:
        while 1:
            response = await websocket.recv()
        
            response_dict = json.loads(response)
            response_list = extract_values(response_dict, [], [])
            for keyvaluepair in response_list:
                my_socketio_client.emit('message_from_websocketserver', {'messageId':keyvaluepair[0], 'value':keyvaluepair[1]})
    
asyncio.run(listen_to_websocket_server())
```

I thought this might be a solution, but i don't understand how to use the websocket in the function `on_message(data)` of `my_socketio_client` or if this is even possible. The problem is, `on_message(data)` gets called once upon an event, but i think it is not possible to use a running websocket in this function. The only solution i see is to always connect a new websocket upon `on_message(data)` but this would be inefficient. Is there an option to use one websocket and assign it to a global variable or something, so i could recieve and send via the same websocket but in multiple functions?
afaik

```
websocket = websockets.connect(...)
```

does not work, because then `websocket.recv()` says that a `Connect`-Object does not have a recv method. Also afaik, a websocket needs to be async and can only be used in async functions, which `on_message(data)` is not.

I was thinking about using a queue, but still, i need a websocket that recieves and sends in two different functions and don't want to use two websockets for that (because i don't even think this is possible due to the implementation of the server where my websocket connects to).

i already saw [python-websocket-server-forwards-messages-from-other-websocket-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62124268/python-websocket-server-forwards-messages-from-other-websocket-server) but they did not provide any solution

Answer (score 0):

i solved it using create_connection that made it able to have a global websocket and have it used in the socketio function callback `on_message(data)`

[Is there a WebSocket client implemented for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142705/is-there-a-websocket-client-implemented-for-python)

```
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection("ws://localhost:8080/websocket")
print "Sending 'Hello, World'..."
ws.send("Hello, World")
print "Sent"
print "Receiving..."
result =  ws.recv()
print "Received '%s'" % result
ws.close()
```